# Th Keyboard does not show up when I press a button once, but when I press a button for a long time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I add a click on uitextfield, the keyboard does not show when touched only with a long press in the field.
What can I do to make the keyboard pop up when I press it and I won't hold it for a long time?
TAP TAP works and deletes other views as well ...
What am I doing wrong?

```
class DeparturesView: UIViewController {
…
    private let searchTextFieldData: UISearchTextField = {
        let searchTextFieldData = UISearchTextField()
        searchTextFieldData.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchTextFieldData.keyboardType = .alphabet
        searchTextFieldData.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        searchTextFieldData.autocorrectionType = .no
        searchTextFieldData.spellCheckingType = .no
        searchTextFieldData.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        searchTextFieldData.backgroundColor = .white
        searchTextFieldData.returnKeyType = .search
        return searchTextFieldData
    }()
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
…
        //Mark - Add gesture to app
        func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
            return touch.view == self.view
        }
        //Mark - Hide keyboard
        let hideKeyboards = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
        hideKeyboards.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(hideKeyboards)
        
        //Mark - Detele other view and show keyboard
        let hideTableView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHandler))
        hideTableView.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        hideTableView.delegate = self
        searchTextFieldData.addGestureRecognizer(hideTableView)

    }
    @objc func tapHandler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("Show tap tap")
        favouriteLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        tableViewWithFavouriteBusStop.removeFromSuperview()
    }

extension DeparturesView: UITextFieldDelegate{
 
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow staps

1. Remove "hideTableView" TapGesture
2. add `self.earchTextFieldData.delegate = self` in viewDidLoad and
3. replace "textFieldDidBeginEditing"

   ```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
       favouriteLabel.removeFromSuperview()
       tableViewWithFavouriteBusStop.removeFromSuperview()
       becomeFirstResponder()
    }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to solve it by

extension DeparturesView: UITextFieldDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
 
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        becomeFirstResponder()
       
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizer(
      _ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
      shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer
    ) -> Bool {
      return true
    }

Once i moved the code to extension it works fine.

Comment: @JakubBąk Do not give the answer in a comment. If you have solved the problem, so that you are no longer in need of help, give the solution in an answer (which you can even accept), or else delete the question.